# How to disable toggling of DAG on/off for read-only user?

Tags: airflow, readonly

I have created admin user (using username and password, using the `create_user` command in the `entrypoint.sh` file).

Now I want to create a new user (read only) from the security tab of Airflow 1.10.10.

I have created the new user and a new role. And the new created role is assigned to that new user.

But I don't want that user to be able to click on the "on/off" option for any of the DAGs. That user should have only read only access, for which I selected the "can_dag_read_on_all_dags" option in the permissions under that role.

But still that user can click the "on -> on/off" button of dags. I don't want that user to click on it as want to keep it read-only.

Please suggest what needs to be done on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to create Viewer role user and try logging in as that user ?

Please take a look at this documentation and let me know.

https://www.cloudwalker.io/2020/03/01/airflow-rbac-role-based-access-control/

Comment: Thanks. I already modified my code to set role of Viewer.